# If $f:X⟶Y$ is such that $f|_U$ is a bijection for $U∈\mathcal P(X)$ then does the equality $f[V∩U]=f[V]∩f[U]$ holds when $V$ and $U$ are not disjoint?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples

Given a function from a set $X$ to a set $Y$ such then I am trying to prove or disprove that if $f|_U$ is a bijection then for any $V\in\mathcal P(X)$ not disjoint from $U$ the equality
$$
f[V\cap U]=f[V]\cap f[U]
$$
holds. So by a general theorem I know that
$$
f[V\cap U]\subseteq f[V]\cap f[U]
$$
but unfortunately I am not able to prove or disprove the reverse inclusion: so could someone help me, please?

Comment: Just to double check, $U$ and $V$ are any subsets of $X$, right? (I suppose that $\mathcal P(X)$ is the set of subsets of $X$, sometimes also denoted as $2^X$.)

Comment: @PavelKocourek You are right.

Comment: "By a general theorem" ... which theorem do you refer to?

Comment: It is a well knew result that if $\varphi$ is a function from $\Nu$ to $\Mu$ then for any $\Lambda_1,\Lambda_2$ contained in $\Nu$ the inclusion $$\varphi[\Lambda_1\cap\Lambda_2]\subseteq\varphi[\Lambda_1]\cap\varphi[\Lambda_2]$$ holds. Moreover it is a very knew result that the last inclusion is an equality if $\varphi$ is injective and viceversa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is an contra-example:**

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be given by $f(x)=x^2$, and let $U=[0,\infty)$ and $V=(-\infty,0]$. Then $f|_U$ is a bijection, but
$$
  f(U \cap V) = f(\{0\}) = \{0\},
$$
whilst
$$
  f(U) \cap f(V) = \mathbb R_+ \cap \mathbb R_+ = \mathbb R_+.
$$

Comment: Very nice: answer upvoted and approved. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

If $y\in f[U]\cap f[V]$ then exist $a\in U$ and $b\in V$ such that
$f(a)=f(b)=y$, but $a,b\in U\cup V$ and $f|_{U\cup V}$ is a bijection then $a=b$ and $a\in U\cap V$, so $y\in f(U\cap V)$.

Comment: @janmrqz Why $f|_{U\cup V}$ must be a bijection? I only say that $f|_U$ is a bjection.

Comment: by your hypothesis $f|_W$ is a  bijection for $W\subset X$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro on a second and third thoughts I failed

Comment: I am supposing that $f|_U$ for **one** $U\in\mathcal P(X)$ is a bijection and so I suppose that $V$ is not disjoint from $U$.

Comment: right! at least you have an extra modified exercise

Comment: Well, if $f|_U$ is a bijection for **each** $U\in\mathcal P(X)$ then by the equality $$f=f|_X$$ $f$ is ijective and so the result holds by a very knew theorem.

Comment: OMG, I'm still suffering of new year's hangover! XD

Comment: Do not worry: it can happen!!! ;-)